# How to solve Flutter app build fail (Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.)?

Tags: android, flutter, build

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\bookingapp\Fook\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\bookingapp\Fook\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-hi\values-hi.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\bookingapp\Fook\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-de\values-de.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> > Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\bookingapp\Fook\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-lo\values-lo.xml: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found the problem it was my antivirus that was restricting AAPT to execute and make change in protected folder

1. Disable File Safeguard
2. Allow AAPT to Execute

Comment: and how do you do those 2 things....?

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build:

```
flutter clean
```

Then try running on another device:

```
flutter run -d DeviceName --release
```

If you do not need to debug, but you still need logs then a release configuration or a profile config should work for you **--profile**

Comment: still no change

Comment: try running on a physical device.  "gphone x86" looks like an emulator.

Comment: tried that too but still no change, finding for solution for almost 3 days

Comment: can you post the entire log entry that you are seeing on the terminal? Make sure to reset the verbosity level. So run the command: "flutter run -d DeviceName --release -v"

Comment: After getting the entire log on your IDE, please add it to the thread.

Comment: finally found the problem it was my antivirus that was restricting AAPT to execute and make change in protected folder